# Publish .NET Core 3.0 web app to Azure cloud

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to publish an .NET Core 3.0 web app to the Azure cloud but apparently, version 3.0 is not supported yet. I've tried several things but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help, please?

...

now I'm getting this error:

[Error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz63v.png)

Update:

I see this is the log, btw.:

IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.

IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.

The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.

The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a web app with .net core 2.x version. And then use Azure web app extension to install .net core 3.0 runtime environment:

[image]

The tutorial: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip21.html

---

Update:

From the kudu advanced tools, I see that the azure web app already has supported .net core 3.0.

[image]

And I can successfully deploy my .net core 3.0 web app to it:

[image]

---

Suggestions;

1. You can update your Visual Studio 2019 to last version, and try again. Try to deploy to a new web app in VS to see if it helps.
2. You can ignore the error, and deploy your website manually. ([FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp), [Zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip) ).

Comment: Thanks, but if I change my Visual Studio web project to use .net core 2.x instead of 3.0, it doesn't build. I'm using a lot of features in .net core 3.0. So what can I do then? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you and I don't have to change the .net version of my project?

Comment: You can still develop your web application with .net core 3.0.  At the same time, you need to add .net core 3.0 extension in your web app, then it will support .net core 3.0, though you cannot choose 3.0 when you create the web app.

Comment: If I just change my Visual Studio web app project to use .NET 2.2 instead of .NET Core 3.0, I get build errors and I'm not able to publish the web onto Azure without fixing those errors. But my code is using a lot of .NET Core 3.0 features. Perhaps I'm not understanding you fully. ??

Comment: Did you see the image in my answer? If you add the asp.net core 3.0 extension for your web app in azure potral，the web app would be able to host your 3.0 website. There is nothing to do with .net core 2.x. You do not neet to change your project at all.

Comment: The extension just adds additional .net core environment support for your web app.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Thanks so much. But it's still not working. When I publish, I get the error that I just added (edited) in my question post above (top of page). So I'm still stuck. Any idea?

Comment: I tried with the last Visual Studio 2019, and everything works fine. And I checked that the Azure web app supports .net core 3.0 by default. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Jack, but the problem still remains. I downloaded Visual Studio 2019 last week and created the Azure web app a few days ago. I use the latest version of .net core on both and I've tried a bunch of other methods. I still get the error message that I updated my original post with: "Your application requires the .NET Core 3.0.0 runtime, but Microsoft Azure App Service only supports the following versions: 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.2.6, 2.2.7 and 3.0.0"

Comment: ...however, I did get some error in the logs. Check the original post for an update!